# Searching for multiple words using TextPad

Tags: textpad

I need to find a list of files that contain 2 different words. For example, I need to search for a list of files from a folder that contain the word "Balloon" and then from the result, need to search for files that contain the word "burst".

Is it possible to do this using Textpad?

Comment: I basically need to search for files that has both the words, "balloon" and "burst". I need to do this with a single reg exp. Is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Edited answer because I see what you want is, in effect, to find any file with *both* balloon **and** burst in. You can simply use `balloon.*burst` (or `balloon.+burst` if you don't want to match **balloonburst** in the file):

[image: TextPad Find with Regex]

Don't forget to search *In all documents* - and my advice would be to hit Mark All to show the results. Bearing in mind you'd need to open these files in TextPad first.